# Java Jar and Classpath problems

Tags: java, macos, scripting, jar

I've got a weird problem that I can't understand... I have a simple HelloWorld jar that I built in Eclipse which has the `Apache Loggings` jar on it's classpath. I've written a script to run the jar:

```
#!/bin/sh
export CLASSPATH=lib/*:$CLASSPATH
java -jar HelloWorld.jar
```

The directory structure here is a main directory with the `HelloWorld.jar` and a `lib` subdirectory holding the `commons-logging-1.1.1.jar`.

Running this script works fine. However, when I place the `HelloWorld.jar` into the `lib` directory (i.e. to contain all the JARs in one place), and executing `java -jar lib/HelloWorld.jar`, I get:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
```

error. Why?!?!?!?!

I'm asking this because I've used the JarBundler on OSX to create an Application bundle for the HelloWorld app and placed a modified script in the `MacOS` directory whereas all the libs are placed in the `Resources/Java` directory. Modified version of the script is:

```
#!/bin/sh
RESOURCE_DIR=$(cd "../Resources"; pwd)
export CLASSPATH=$RESOURCE_DIR/Java/*:$CLASSPATH
java -jar $RESOURCE_DIR/Java/HelloWorld.jar
```

and I'm getting the same error as above I'd really appreciate any help understanding why I can't do this and/or how to fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Classpath doesn't work with wildcards. Every jar has to be specified explicitly, either as part of the CLASSPATH variable or in the manifest of another jar that is included in the classpath.

Also, IIRC java -jar ignores all the third party jars that are present in the classpath. Why not do this instead?

```
java -cp yourJar:logJars <mainClass>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to add the commons-logging-1.1.1.jar to the CLASSPATH directly

Comment: I've tried that, (see my comment to @Sarel Botha) but it still hasn't worked.

Comment: Yes I suppose it is the -jar that is causing that... I think the @Jagat solution should work.

Answer (score 2):

Java will not work with lib/* but the shell may be expanding it for you. Double check this. Put a line like this after export:

```
echo $CLASSPATH
```

Also, I would recommend putting it in the MANIFEST file as already mentioned.

EDIT:
Is it a permission problem? If you run the app as root/admin or put the file somewhere else and use a fully-qualified path does it work?

Comment: the `echo $CLASSPATH` yields `/Users/sonogenics/Documents/workspace/HelloWorld/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:` which is where I expect it to be but I'm still getting the error...

Comment: Running the script as sudo still doesn't fix the problems. I'm going mad! But thanks for the input!

Comment: I think Jagat has the right answer. When you use -jar I know it ignores -classpath. It probably ignores $CLASSPATH too.

Answer (score 1):

Use the MANIFEST file (META-INF folder) to deal with Classpath entries. Use relative paths for the libraries.

For further info, take a look [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html).

Basically, for the case with commons-logging inside a lib folder:

```
Class-Path: lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
```

And for both jars in the same folder:

```
Class-Path: commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everyone for their help in figuring this out. Basically, a manifest file was being created and bundled into the jar without my knowledge so any `$CLASSPATH` or `-cp` flags were being ignored. In my Eclipse project, I had my classpath set to `$(projectRoot)/lib` which coincidentally the same directory structure as my `dist` directory. However, when they were bundled into one directory by OSX's JarBundler, the directory was no long present, hence the classpath errors!

I tried removing the `Class-Path` attribute from the `MANIFEST.MF` that Eclispe created but the command line `$CLASSPATH` and/or `-cp` entries still don't seem to make a difference... Does the existence of a manifest file negate all command line classpath entries?

Comment: I is not good practice to ask questions inside of questions. Please, from now on, ask new questions or update your question with relevant information.
As for your answer `java -jar` will ignore external classpath settings (it has nothing to do with the presence of MANIFEST Class-path). You can use @Jagat `-cp` solution to manage the classpath yourself... But, I can't stress enough that there is no reason to reinvent the well, just set your classpath correctly in your MANIFEST file or let JarBundler do it for you. [Ant task](http://informagen.com/JarBundler/).

Comment: Just to be more specific, I'm talking about `jarfileset` and `jarfileset` options. Do not use `extraclasspath`* options to include commons-logging.

Answer (score 0):

have you set log4j.jar into your class. i think you didnt added log4j.jar of to its class path.